# win10 universal app, async задержка

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

Имеется такой код:

```
static StorageFolder Folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

public static async Task<StorageFile> GetFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        return await Folder.CreateFileAsync(path, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

С помощью которого выполняются некоторые действия с файлом.

По какой-то причине при заходе в этот метод происходит зависание - процесс висит и ничего не происходит. Ни исключений, ничего.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как её решить.

updt.
Вызывающий метод:

```
var temp = DataManager.LoadObject<ObservableCollection<CheckingResult>>(await DataManager.GetFile(Path.FilePath)).Result
```

Comment: Эээ, а зачем ловить исключение, чтобы тут же его снова бросить (потеряв при этом его настоящий тип)?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который вызывает `GetFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
var temp = (some code).Result
```

Вызов `Result` останавливает текущий поток до тех пор пока задача не завершится. Но для выхода из оператора `await` нужен работающий поток!

Отсюда и взаимоблокировка.

Никогда не вызывайте `Task.Result` или `Task.Wait()` в потоке UI!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы вызываете метод из UI-потока без ключевого слова await и у вас происходит взаимоблокировка UI-потока и потока, в котором открывается файл. Метод должен использоваться следующим образом:

```
var file = await YourClass.GetFile(yourPath);
```

По этой теме рекомендую хорошую [статью (англ. яз.)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), а конкретно раздел Async All the Way

Comment: Да, эта ошибка имеется, но если это опустить, файл должен загрузиться через некоторое время (там не так уж и много информации, простой .dat'ник с сериализованными данными)

Comment: Пропуск ключевого слова `await` сам по себе не приводит к взаимоблокировке

Comment: @PavelMayorov, сам по себе нет, в вашем ответе тоже речь про UI-поток. Очевидно, что без await только через Result и можно достать результат, поэтому не вижу у нас с вами противоречий

Comment: @ArtemFlotsky нет, словосочетание "без await" означает не использование `.Result` - а поведение "вызвал и забыл". Такое поведение рождает гонки, но не взаимоблокировку.

Answer (score 1):

[Async/await в C#: подводные камни](https://habrahabr.ru/post/257221/)

Если не нужен вызов внутри потока UI предпочтительнее использовать
**.ConfigureAwait(false);**

```
 return await Folder.CreateFileAsync(path, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

В статье как раз описан твой случай.

Ну и конечно лучше использовать await вместо Result

> Если вы разрабатываете стороннюю библиотеку, очень важно всегда
>   настраивать await таким образом, чтобы остальная часть метода была
>   выполнена произвольным потоком из пула. Другими словами, в коде
>   сторонних библиотек всегда необходимо добавлять ConfigureAwait(false).
>
> В первую очередь, сторонние библиотеки обычно не работают с UI
>   контролами (если конечно это не UI библиотека), поэтому нет никакой
>   необходимости связывать UI поток. Вы можете немного увеличить
>   производительность если позволите CLR выполнять ваш код любым потоком
>   из пула. Во-вторых, используя дефолтную имплементацию (или явно
>   проставляя ConfigureAwait(true)), вы оставляете потенциальную дыру для
>   дедлоков. Рассмотрим следующий пример:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = DoSomeWorkAsync().Result; // 1
}

private async Task<int> DoSomeWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(true); //2
    return 1;
}
```

> Клик по кнопке здесь приводит к дедлоку. UI поток стартует новый I/O
>   поток на строке «2» и уходит в спящий режим на строке «1», ожидая
>   завершения работы. После того как I/O поток заканчивает выполнение,
>   оставшаяся часть метода DoSomeWorkAsync передается на выполнение
>   вызывающему (UI) потоку. Но тот в это время находится в спящем режиме,
>   ожидая завершения метода. Дедлок.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38854/discussion-on-answer-by-serginio-win10-universal-app-async-).