# Виснет UI поток во время while

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tcp-ip, tcp, async-await

Почему у меня виснет UI поток когда я делаю `While`, не ну это было понятно если бы я бы этот цикл сделал в обычном методе, так я сделал метод асинхронным и всё равно виснет, почему?

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true) // С этим while'ом работает всё ок
            {
                Task processTask = Process(lastclient);
            }
        }

async Task Process(TcpClient result)
        {
            ...  тут что-то происходит
            while (true) // С этим while'ом всё повисает
            {
                result.Client.Receive(recievebytes);
            }
        }
```

**UPD 1** :

```
    SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgObjectForPool = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    eventArgObjectForPool.UserToken = users.Last<TcpClient>().Client;

    result.Client.ReceiveFromAsync(eventArgObjectForPool); //Вот тут вылетает, какого то параметра не хватает внутри eventArgObjectForPool
```

**UPD 2** :

```
    TcpListener listener;
    TcpClient user;

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //По нажатии на клавишу запускаем наш серв
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(listenPort);
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient user = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()
        while (true)
        {
            Process(user); //Если клиент подключён, то начинаем с ним работать
        }
    }

    async Task Process(TcpClient result)
    {
        //Тут настраиваем слушалку для клиента

        SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgObjectForPool = new SocketAsyncEventArgs(); 
        eventArgObjectForPool.UserToken = user.Client;
        eventArgObjectForPool.RemoteEndPoint = user.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
        eventArgObjectForPool.Completed += EventArgObjectForPool_Completed;
        listener.Server.ReceiveFromAsync(eventArgObjectForPool); // Вот это я как понимаю ставлю обработчик на входящие сообщения
    }

    private void EventArgObjectForPool_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ads"); // Если что-то приходит от клиента, то выводим в консоль строку какую-нибудь.
    }
```

Comment: А где return или break?

Comment: Вам не кажется, что `TcpClient user = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()` стоило внести внутрь `while`?

Comment: `async Task Process` какой-то слишком синхронный. Где там await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.Client.Receive(recievebytes);` - это синхронный вызов. Разумеется, поток UI будет висеть - он же синхронно читает из сокета в бесконечном цикле!

Либо **найдите** асинхронную версию метода `Receive`:

```
async Task Process(TcpClient result)
{
     while(true)
     {
          count += await result.Client.ReceiveAsync(recievebytes);
     }
}
```

Либо вынесите чтение в отдельный поток.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43621/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov--ui----while).

Answer (score -1):

[win10 universal app, async задержка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512968/win10-universal-app-async-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0/513241#513241)

await listener.Server.ReceiveFromAsync(eventArgObjectForPool).ConfigureAwait(false);

И [Зависает оператор `await` в оконном приложении / программа висит при вызове Task.Result или Wait](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514529/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-await-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-task/514533#514533)

Опять же

```
TcpClient user = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()
```

будет выполняться в потоке UI. Это нужно?

```
TcpClient user = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

И дальнейшее выполнение будет в потоке отличным от UI

Comment: а откуда мне брать `eventargobjectforpool`?

Comment: У NetworkStream есть метод ReadAsync https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx если предусмотрена передача размера, то можно самому организовать все события

Comment: Хорошо, попробую