# Программа виснет после вызова метода while(true)

Tags: c#, winforms

Решил я программу написать которая выводит время и каждую 1 секунду обновляет форму Label1 но вот случилась проблема, после вызова while true программа просто напросто зависает и даже не выводится на экран но висит в процессах. Можете помочь мне разобраться в чем дело?

```
private void gettime()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string time =  DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        this.label1.Text = time;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    gettime();
}
```

Comment: Проблема ваша понятна и проста. Вы запускаете бесконечный цикл, из которого нет выхода. Основной UI поток нельзя так блокировать, иначе приложение виснет, подобные вопросы уже не раз всплывали на сайте. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550649/213987

Answer (score 1):

Получилось исправить с помощью добавления таймера на форму и вызова через него нужной функции.

```
private void Timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        gettime();
    }
```